# Node.js calling a callback function inside loop scope issue

Tags: node.js, for-loop, callback, scope

I am building the following code:

```
for(var i=0;i<datos.length;i++){
   bittrex.getticker(datos[i].Currency,function(err, data){
        if (err){
            console.log('ERROR:', err);
            return 'ERROR:'+ err;
        } else {
            if (data.message!='INVALID_MARKET') {
                 datos[i].LasValueBTC=data.result.Last;
            } else {
                 datos[i].LasValueBTC='';   
            }  
        }
    });
}
```

ok i get an error message: "Cannot set property 'LasValueBTC' of undefined". So i guessed that i variable is not being understood inside the callback function.. 
I tried without success:

```
for(var i=0;i<datos.length;i++){
   bittrex.getticker(datos[i].Currency,(function(err, data){
        if (err){
            console.log('ERROR:', err);
            return 'ERROR:'+ err;
        } else {
            if (data.message!='INVALID_MARKET') {
                 datos[i].LasValueBTC=data.result.Last;
            } else {
                 datos[i].LasValueBTC='';   
            }  
        }
    })(i)); //and also i tried }).bind(this,i)); 
}
```

How is this solved?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that `getticker` is asynchronous while the `for` loop is synchronous, so the value of `i` is probably not what you're expecting it to be by the time you access `datos[i]`. A simple solution for this is as follows:

```
for(var i=0;i<datos.length;i++){
   bittrex.getticker(datos[i].Currency, function(err, data){
        if (err){
            console.log('ERROR:', err);
            return 'ERROR:'+ err;
        } else {
            if (data.message!='INVALID_MARKET') {
                 this.LasValueBTC=data.result.Last;
            } else {
                 this.LasValueBTC='';   
            }  
        }
    }.bind(datos[i]));
}
```

Comment: thanks @glortho. After doing what you suggest if i console.log(this) inside the function  works great and this.LastValueBTC exists in my json, but outside the function if i console.log(datos) after the loop, the LastValueBTC does not exist..and i need to do a res.send(datos) after the loop..

Comment: Okay @Aitor that's a different (but related) question, which I can also help you with. Post that separately and let me know when it's up.

Comment: mmm i can only post every 90 minutes... :(

Comment: Okay, an easy solution to your issue can be found by using this library to call a callback once all asynchronous functions have finished: https://github.com/caolan/async , but you may need to spend some time becoming familiar with the library first.